# Oval collision detection not working properly

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, geometry

So I'm trying to implement a test where a oval can connect with a circle, but it's not working.

```
edist = (float) Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow((px + ((pwidth/2) )) - (bx + (bsize/2)), 2 ) + 
    Math.pow(-((py + ((pwidth/2)) ) - (bx + (bsize/2))), 2 )
);
```

and here is the full code (requires Slick2D):

```
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class ColTest extends BasicGame{


    float px = 50;
    float py = 50;
    float pheight = 50;
    float pwidth = 50;



    float bx = 200;
    float by = 200;
    float bsize = 200;

    float edist;

    float pspeed = 3;
    Input input;

    public ColTest()
    {
        super("ColTest");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc)
            throws SlickException {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta)
            throws SlickException
    {
        input = gc.getInput();

        try{    
            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP))   
                py-=pspeed;

            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) 
                py+=pspeed;

            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) 
                px-=pspeed;

            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))    
                px+=pspeed;
        }

        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException
    {   
            g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
            g.drawString("col: " + col(), 10, 10);
            g.drawString("edist: " + edist + " dist: " + dist, 10, 100);

            g.fillRect(px, py, pwidth, pheight);
            g.setColor(new Color(255,0,255));
            g.fillOval(px, py, pwidth, pheight);
            g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 200, 200);

    }

    public boolean col(){

        edist = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((px + ((pwidth/2) )) - (bx + (bsize/2)), 2) + Math.pow(-((py + ((pwidth/2)) ) - (bx + (bsize/2))), 2));

        if(edist <= (bsize/2) + (px + (pwidth/2)))
            return true;

        else
            return false;
    }

    public float rotate(float x, float y, float ox, float oy, float a, boolean b)
    {
         float dst = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-ox,2.0)+ Math.pow(y-oy,2.0));

         float oa = (float) Math.atan2(y-oy,x-ox);

         if(b)
            return (float) Math.cos(oa + Math.toRadians(a))*dst+ox;

         else
            return (float) Math.sin(oa + Math.toRadians(a))*dst+oy;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws SlickException
    {
         AppGameContainer app =
            new AppGameContainer( new ColTest() );

         app.setShowFPS(false);
         app.setAlwaysRender(true);
         app.setTargetFrameRate(60);
         app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
         app.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"? What do you expect your program to do?

Comment: I think what he means is that the ovals not colliding with the circle.

Comment: Compilation error:

/home/dlee/tmp/collision/src/main/java/collision/ColTest.java:[67,57] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable dist
location: class collision.ColTest

Answer (score 2):

Is using ovals an absolute requirement? You can approximate collisions between fancier shapes by representing them with multiple circles. That way you can use very a simple collision detection between circles and still achieve a high level of accuracy for the viewer.

```
collision(c1, c2) {
  dx = c1.x - c2.x;
  dy = c1.y - c2.y;
  dist = c1.radius + c2.radius;

  return (dx * dx + dy * dy <= dist * dist)
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [strd6.com](http://strd6.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/circle_collisions.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Finding the intersection is harder than you think.  Your `col()` method is a bit off, but that approach will at best be able to tell you if a single point is within the circle.  It won't be able to really detect intersections.

I Googled up some code for computing the actual intersections.  I found [one in JavaScript](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm#Anchor-intersectCircleEllips-14169) that's really interesting and really complicated.  Take a look at [the source](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/Intersection.js).

If you wanted something a bit simpler (but less accurate), you could check a few points around the ellipse to see if they're within the circle.

```
private boolean isInCircle(float x, float y) {
    float r = bsize / 2;
    float center_x = bx + r;
    float center_y = by + r;
    float dist = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - center_x, 2) + Math.pow(y - center_y, 2));

    return dist < r;
}

public boolean col() {
    return 
        isInCircle(px + pwidth / 2, py              ) || // top
        isInCircle(px + pwidth    , py + pheight / 2) || // right
        isInCircle(px + pwidth / 2, py + pheight    ) || // bottom
        isInCircle(px             , py + pheight / 2);   // left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on implementing more shapes and/or need the minimum distance between your shapes, you could start using [GJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) : you would only need to implement the support functions for each new shape. If computation time is also critical, GJK is definitely something you should look at, but it would surely require some more programming on your side.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find your foci you can check for collision with the pseudo code below.
WARNING this only works for two ellipse collisions (ellipse and circle collisions work also).

```
r = length of semi major axis
a_x = x coordinate of foci 1 of the first ellipse
a_y = y coordinate of foci 1 of the first ellipse
b_x = x coordinate of foci 2 of the first ellipse
b_y = y coordinate of foci 2 of the first ellipse

c_x = x coordinate of foci 1 of the second ellipse
c_y = y coordinate of foci 1 of the second ellipse
d_x = x coordinate of foci 2 of the second ellipse
d_y = y coordinate of foci 2 of the second ellipse

p_x = (a_x+b_x+c_x+d_x)/4 // i.e. the average of the foci x values
p_y = (a_y+b_y+c_y+d_y)/4 // i.e. the average of the foci y values

if r >= ( sqrt( (p_x + a_x)^2+(p_y + a_y)^2 ) + sqrt( (p_x + a_x)^2+(p_y + a_y)^2 ) )
then collision
```

If you really want the derivation of this let me know and I'll provide it. But it uses the idea that the sum of the distances between the foci of an ellipse and any point on the edge of an ellipse are a set distance apart (the semi major axis). And solves for a point that is on the edge of both ellipsoids and if one exist then their is a collision.