# How to check if two oval like objects are overlapping?

Tags: java

I have a small prototype that I'm currently working on. I wanted to implement collision detection and I already succeeded implementing it for rectangular shaped objects. Now, I want to implement the same for an oval object.

In general, I just want a method that checks if a sphere/oval shaped object overlaps with another sphere/oval shaped like object.

**EDIT:**
This question is **not** a duplicate of the [Oval collision detection not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836184/oval-collision-detection-not-working-properly) thread, due to the Reason that that question is related to an error in the program and not in the general concept of comparing two oval shaped objects.

Further more, the answer in the above mentioned thread is not marked as accepted. Therefore linking to that question is not a duplication, but rather linking to a source.

Comment: You need to check every pixel one by one. Maybe if you know its formula then you can create an algorithm to find overlap status.

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3080249/784540

Comment: @RafaelOsipov If you create an answer linking to the thread, I would mark it as accepted! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ToxicTV posted my comment as a response

Comment: @RafaelOsipov You just have to wait approximately seven minutes until I can accept your answer.

Comment: @ToxicTV ok, no problem :)

Comment: @ToxicTV In your post, you mentioned `in general, I just want a method that checks if a sphere/oval shaped object overlaps with another sphere/oval shaped like object.` with no indication it must be on slick2D and you are indeed just asking for a general idea on the implementation which has no direct like to slick2D as well. Further more, you accepted the answer (which is identical) to another SO post further proves that the answer from the other post is enough to fulfil your needs, hence making this question a duplicate.

Comment: @ToxicTV Even if you were asking in the context of C++, it is still a duplicate because the solution to your question is not language/engine specific. You just asked for a general formula/algorithm to detect the collision.

Comment: After my latest edit, there is no way you can deny the fact that my thread is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oval can be substituted by poligon (with any precision you need by increasing side count). Then the problem will be to intersect 2 poligons. It can be done by splitting poligon to triangles, for example, and reduce problem to "triangles collision".

Comment: Just come new idea: do not split oval to triangles. Instead-approximate oval with some vertical (or horizontal) rectangles (more rectangles = more precision). Then it will be trivial to check rectangles intersections.